# Does C++/WinRT offer a helper function to construct a GUID from a string literal?

Tags: c++-winrt

Unlike C++/CX, there doesn't appear to be a wrapper type for GUIDs in C++/WinRT. It just uses the plain C [GUID struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa373931.aspx) as-is. So the only way to construct an initialized GUID is by using [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) syntax, e.g.

```cpp
GUID const guid{ 0x00000000, 0x0000, 0x0000,{ 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 } };
```

While that works (and the *Create GUID* tool in Visual Studio can even be set to generate the initializer code for you) it's just tedious, far from readable, and always has me scratching my head whether I introduced any endian-ness issues.

I'd much rather like to write (using a hypothetical `make_guid` function)

```cpp
auto const guid{ make_guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") };
```

I know that C++/WinRT does a lot of `constexpr` magic to calculate GUIDs from fully-qualified type names, so presumably it is possible to implement a zero-overhead compile time `make_guid` function. Browsing the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/winrt) and *winrt/base.h*, I didn't spot anything that's immediately applicable.

Does C++/WinRT provide a helper function to construct a GUID from a string literal at compile time? If not, can we/I have one?

Comment: The olden `__uuidof()` extension is still around, gets used in base.h by the guid<> template.  All you should need is `__declspec(uuid("yadayada"))` to tell the compiler about it.  Fake a struct if necessary.

Comment: There is an example [right here](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/master/10.0.16299.0/winrt/base.h#L2946).

Comment: @HansPassant: That doesn't construct a `GUID`. It attaches a `GUID` to a type, that can be retrieved using `__uuidof`. This is even more verbose than using the aggregate initialization, and introduces fake types. Not entirely what I was looking for.

Comment: It does, use guid<> to retrieve it.  Nice if you can declare the type correctly and recommended.  But certainly not necessary, any struct will do.  You are very picky btw.

Comment: The number 1 time sink for developer time is reading code. Being picky about the code others have to read to reason about it is a justifiable investment. In this specific case there do not seem to be any unsolved problems in producing an implementation, that concisely conveys intent. Faking types, on the other hand, accomplishes the opposite: It introduces code (that others have to read), which does not contribute towards a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, C++/WinRT does not currently provide such a helper. When the constexpr GUID code was originally written, the C++ compiler's support for constexpr was rather brittle and slow. I thus avoided any unnecessary computation. The constexpr support has however improved quite a bit. Anyway, a constexpr make_guid function is doable with a sufficiently advanced compiler. Here is an example:

https://gist.github.com/kennykerr/6c948882de395c25b3218ad8d4daf362

Comment: Not too much magic after all. Any chance of getting this into the C++/WinRT library, or is this just not important enough to justify the maintenance/support costs?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable addition. I'll see what I can do. Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: The `sv` suffix can be omitted from the literal. `make_guid("8AA90CAD-fed1-4c54-89db-9B7522D8AA92")` compiles successfully and is easier to read.

Comment: Hi @KennyKerr. If that code gets added would you mind also adding a guid-to-string helper too? At the moment all i've found is the Win32 function StringFromCLSID.

Not a big deal I know but it's nice to avoid bringing in old APIs.

Comment: Actually scratch that function. I am using winrt::guid which you can't easily use with StringFromCLSID

Comment: Ignore everything I said. Just discovered this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/to-hstring.

Comment: Looks like the `constexpr` string view constructors were introduced in [v2.0.210122.3](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/releases/tag/2.0.210122.3). Could you double-check, and ideally update this answer?

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Kenny is very helpful. I am just adding a bit update on GUID in Windows 10 SDK.

GUID has been projected to "winrt::guid" since Windows 10, version 1809. And it is now a fundemental type in C++/WinRT. Here is the [release note on Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/news#news-and-changes-in-windows-sdk-version-100177630-windows-10-version-1809).

Beside, there is a helper to construct a GUID from empty. Please refer to the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.guidhelper.createnewguid?view=winrt-19041

Answer (score 0):

For future readers like myself, there is now a `winrt::guid` constructor that accepts a string:

```cpp
auto id = winrt::guid("4c8dfbdc-97c8-4a34-b394-0c439f2a0118");
```

[Relevant PR](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/pull/833)